# Can someone help me launch my spring boot application? Going into loop and and not proceeding further

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have been trying to launch my application. But getting only the following image and not proceeding further.

```
JVMJ9VM193W Since Java 13 -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated for removal and may not be accepted options in the future.
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions prior to 1.8.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/Users/manoj.s14/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.6/logback-classic-1.2.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.5)
```

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could also be that Logger is not properly configured. I had once similar very strange behavior.

Comment: Error has been cleared. Its due to log not configured properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check up your `JVM/JDK` installation, if it is well installed, check if your project is linked to your `jvm/jdk` depending on your IDE the method might be different, for intelliJ you can find help [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#configure-external-documentation).